# how to build wrapper script

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

Sort of an odd question, but: how would one go about creating a wrapper shell script that can be used in the #! line in other scripts.

**wrap.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "wrapper!"
exec ruby "$@"
```

**test.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env wrap.sh
puts RUBY_VERSION
puts "the ducks come from the trucks"
```

wrap.sh is in the path, and test.rb is marked as executable.

Now I do:

```
./test.rb
wrapper!
ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)
```

The goal is to execute the ruby script via the wrapper (The ruby version can be either local or comes from a traveling ruby install that is shipped along with the app).
As far as I can tell ruby is invoked, it's just unhappy with the #! in the test.rb and refuses to run the script. I cannot remove the #! because that's how the script is executed in the first place.
**Any workarounds for this?**

So, I **cannot** use rbenv/rvm/etc. There is more logic in the wrapper than this, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: It looks like Ruby just [checks that the hash-bang line contains "ruby"](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_2/ruby.c#L1580).

Comment: ahaha. seems that you're write @matt Including ruby in the name of the wrapper did the trick! do you want to write an answer for this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Ruby just checks that the hash-bang line contains "ruby": https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_2/ruby.c#L1580 So basically having ruby somewhere in the #! line is all it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the arguments are not being passed to Ruby in `"$@"`.  I don't think the bang-hash line is the problem.

I don't see anything in your script which actually passes the contents of test.rb to wrapper.sh, which is the bigger issue.

Perhaps the real problem can be solved by some other means?  For example, is the problem you're trying to solve to run arbitrary commands prior to the invocation of any Ruby script from the command line?  Perhaps it can be approached that way...

Comment: you don't need to pass the contents of the file. just the file name + args. nope: i just want a wrapper that can be used in specific scripts